# Winforms Report (RDLC) binding at run time with an object with a list property

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, rdlc

I have an object that has header level details about an order, as well as a list of order details.

The header information populates just fine, but I can't figure out how to bind the list of order details to the tablix that I have on the report.

Is this the wrong approach? 
The data connection is being determined at run time, so I don't think I can easily just hook a subreport to a database and pass filters.

Edit: I should add that I have a parent form with a ReportViewer, if it makes a difference. That's where I set the datasource.

```
    public class FormulaHeaderModel
{
    public string flavor { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public string formulaId { get; set; }
    public string formulaNumber { get; set; }
    public string formulaType { get; set; }
    public string accessLevel { get; set; }
    public string createdOnDate { get; set; }
    public string formulaWeight { get; set; }
    public string note { get; set; }
    public List<FormulaDetailModel> dataCharacterizing { get; set; }
    public List<FormulaDetailModel> dataContributory { get; set; }
    public List<FormulaDetailModel> dataGlobal { get; set; }
    public List<FormulaDetailModel> dataCarrier { get; set; }
}
    public class FormulaDetailModel
{
    public int formulaID { get; set; }
    public int ingredientTypeId { get; set; }
    public string codeFema { get; set; }
    public decimal ingredientCost { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string natural { get; set; }
    public decimal ppm { get; set; }
    public decimal percentSolution { get; set; }
    public decimal grams {get; set;}
}
```

I need to have a tablix for each of the lists.

So the top is the string level info, then a label and tablix(or whatever really) for each of the 4 FormulaDetailModel lists.

Comment: This sounds like it should be doable - can you share the data structure you're trying to report on?  And the desired output (even a paint mockup of the design would assist)

Comment: just edited to include the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I can add a second datasource as long as the name matches the dataset name that the table is set for.

```
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("FormulaDetailModel", fhModel.dataCharacterizing ));
```